# Storing a 55k+ string in Teradata using the .net client

Tags: c#, .net, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Here we are on day 3 of trying to figure out how to store a very large string into Teradata. I am not going to lie. Last night I took an extra melatonin pill hoping it would elevate me to seer level today but unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out a solution to this issue other than splitting the string in half and storing it in 2 different fields -which I don't like-.

I am attempting to store a 55k+ length of a string in Teradata by using the .net class they have on nuget.

Scenario;

I call a webservice and I receive this very large string which is a base64 encoded image. I am supposed to store this string and this is my .net code / Tdcommand thus far;

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PL1_STAGING.CRS_PHOTO_STG (... MAIN_PHOTO ...) VALUES (... <base64string>...);"
```

Teradata responds with; `3738 String is longer than 31000 characters.`

The Teradata documentation suggests; `To insert longer strings, the user must have a USING clause and a DATA parcel that contain the characters.`

I have attempted that but I haven't been able to import it successfully using a text file. While I am not an expert on Teradata, I have tried to use a `Blob` data type in my .net code but I haven't been able to convert the base64 string to blob in .net so that I can store it that way.

Thank you for the time and sorry for the introduction.

Comment: I can't help how to do this in .NET, but assuming that the target column is a VarChar the maximum size will be 64000 for a Latin Character Set and 32000 for Unicode. If it's larger you need a CLOB, not a BLOB. There should be examples in the documentation how to load CLOBs. Btw, Teradata supports a `'base64m'` encoding for the `to_bytes` function.

Comment: String literals can't be over 31000 characters even though a VARCHAR LATIN column can be much larger. If you are supplying the value within the request text, maybe just split into two literals and concatenate the values in the INSERT, e.g. 'part1'||'part2'. Or if you want to load byte array to BLOB or character array to CLOB the INSERT should have ? as parameter marker and the array supplied as the parameter value - see .NET provider documentation for some examples